# What would be the best translation of the expression “on track”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, expression

I’m currently writing a status report using a “traffic light” system, where the description for “Green” would be “On track”, to note that a certain task is on track with the development plan and and there are no predicted delays.

I assume a proper translation would be “auf der richtigen Spur” or “auf dem richtigen Weg”.

However I doubt it’s appropriate to use any of those expressions in a formal document, or that they express the right idea. Also, it seems too long and unpractical.

Is there a formal term or expression that is usually used in such cases?

Comment: I edited out the gender mistake with *Spur* (which should be feminie).

Comment: Instead of "*auf* der Spur" you could be "*in* der Spur". But that's quite colloquial, Carsten's "im Plan" is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Spur” is feminine, so it would be “auf der richtigen Spur”, but that would be a hunting metaphor.

A fitting but not very formal expression would be “im Plan”.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'm still struggling with articles after 4 years. :) And, correct me if I am mistaken, but wouldn't "im Plan"  rather be understood as "planned" than as "on track" or "on course"?

Comment: @PeterNoble, I think “planned” would be “geplant”. Maybe you are thinking of “in der Planung”, “being planned”.

Comment: @PeterNoble *Im Plan* actually exactly means ‘we have plan *X* and so far we are exactly on track for that plan (or maybe ahead even)’

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you both for the clarification.

Comment: "Im Zeitplan" wäre auch noch ne Alternative, und vermutlich eindeutiger als "im Plan"

Answer (score 3):

Alternativen zu 'im Plan':

- auf Kurs
- im Soll

Comment: Heißt „im Soll“ nicht „verschuldet“?

Comment: Das heißt es bezogen auf Kontostände. Ich sehe aber keine Metapher oder Übertragung. Man soll etwas erledigen und sagt, dass man getan hat, was man sollte. Vielleicht heißt es aber auch dass man noch nicht fertig ist, andererseit aber eben auch nicht im Verzug ist. Da wäre doch die Analogie zum Konto, wenn man einen Kredit bedient.

Comment: Ich habe es nur noch nicht mit der Bedeutung, die Du angibst, gehört. Kann an mir liegen.